# Can we call constructor(props) with other names in react?

Tags: reactjs, class, constructor, super

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
```

Learning react, I always come across those two lines. I understand that the super must be written in order to use the "*this*" method. But why do we always use the word "props"? What if our class holds information about people and we want to pass : (Age, Name, Job)?
Is the following code valid?

```
constructor(Age, Name, Job) {
super(Age, Name, Job);
```

If not, what does "props" trigger inside of React.Component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The React [`Component`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L20) class expects 3 argument to its constructor: `props`, `context` and `updater`.

You could do

```
constructor(Age, Name, Job) {
  super(Age, Name, Job);
```

but you have to keep in mind that you are just renaming `props`, `context` and `updater` here, and it doesn't do anything special.

When you are passing props like

```
<MyComponent age={age} name={name} />
```

They are available as properties of `props`. In the `constructor`, you would access them like this:

```
constructor(props){ 
  super(props);

  console.log('age', props.age);
  console.log('name', props.name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are other information in the props that React.Component needs, so you have to call super(props) otherwise React.Component won't get these important information.

But that doesn't prevent you from using other data inside your constructor, they could be passed as props: props.age, props.name...